# python split lit of tuples to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a list of tuples and I want to convert to multiple lists.

For example, the list of tuples is

```
    [('1','2','3','4'),('3','4','5','6'),('5','6','7','8'),('7','8','9','10'),('9','10','11','12')]
```

Is there a way  in Python that convert it to:

```
   1|2|3|4
   3|4|5|6
   5|6|7|8
   7|8|9|10
   9|10|11|12
```

Comment: There is no built-in function to do this. You have to write the function from scratch.

Comment: you convert a tuple to a list by putting "list()" around it. Your desired output is not a list. If you just want to print them in that format, that's better, but the question is misleading.

Comment: @Kazi Sohan Can you please guide how to write this function

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to convert this into; it certainly doesn't look like one or more Python list(s).

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and detail what specific technical problem you have getting to the desired output? Please also clarify whether you actually want a list (as in, the out data type in a "list of tuples")  or merely format or print an output string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
lst = [('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('3', '4', '5', '6'), ('5', '6', '7', '8'), ('7', '8', '9', '10'), ('9', '10', '11', '12')]

result = list(map(list, zip(*lst)))
print(result)
```

Which yields

```
[['1', '3', '5', '7', '9'], ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10'], ['3', '5', '7', '9', '11'], ['4', '6', '8', '10', '12']]
```

---

Or:

```
result = "\n".join("|".join(tpl) for tpl in lst)
```

Which would yield

```
1|2|3|4
3|4|5|6
5|6|7|8
7|8|9|10
9|10|11|12
```

Answer (score 2):

you can loop through the first list and '|'.join() the tuples, here the code you can try:

```
for x in list1:
    print('|'.join(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = a = [('1','2','3','4'),('3','4','5','6'),('5','6','7','8'),('7','8','9','10'),('9','10','11','12')]
for x in a:
     print(*x, sep="|")
```

```
1|2|3|4
3|4|5|6
5|6|7|8
7|8|9|10
9|10|11|12
```